# Parsehub main_template and renaming

Tags: parsehub

So using the parsehub tool to experiment with data-scraping and wondering if there is a rule to keeping the `main_template` name which is automatically given to all projects. Is it possible to change it and what is the significance of the name and the template itself?

Answer (score 1):

One of the founders of ParseHub here. The name of the template has no significance other than reminding you what the template is for, and allowing you to reference it when starting a run.

For example, if you have two templates, `main_template` and `subcategory_template`, and you want to run the project on just one of the subcategories on the site, you can choose `subcategory_template` as the starting template for one of your runs.

Hope that helps.